# How many users can I share youtube private video?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I have uploaded a YouTube video and marked it as private.

Now I want to share it with my users. How many users can i share my youtube private video.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no limit to the number of users you can share a private video with.  If you are looking for a documented limit your probably not going ot find one Google doesnt like to document things like this as its easier for them to change them at a later date if its not documented.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-many-users-can-I-share-YouTube-private-videos-with

I reffered this link. 
Youtube You Can Share It With A Maximum 50 People's.

Comment: I have just made an experiment, and managed to share my private YouTube video with 51 people. All accounts have to be valid e-mail addressses, and maybe not aliases since that caused some errors in my case.